# 成 as a result complement

Tags: grammar

I have these sentences from my textbook which I mostly understand, but I'm confused about the usage of 成.

”有银行通知我去面试，所以就**穿成**这样了。“

”我们和上次那个公司的生意终于**谈成**了。“

"当别人请你帮忙时，对那些自己很难**办成**的事情，最好还是先想清楚。如果最后事情没**办成**，不仅自己会觉得不好意思，而且别人以后也有可能不再相信你了。"

I'm guessing 成 is a resultant complement, it seems from context to mean something like 完 or 好, indicating completion. If so, how does it differ from them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a resultant complement, both 完 and 好 can indicate 'finish' or 'complete'

Example:

谈完生意 (finish talking business)

做好功課 (finish doing homework)

~

好 can also mean 'properly' or 'well'

Example: 學好中文 (learn Chinese well)

~

As a resultant complement, depending on the context, 成 can mean:

1. 成為 - e.g. 做**成**木偶 (make **into** a puppet); 打成殘廢 (beat **to become** crippled)
2. 成功 - e.g. 谈**成**生意 (**successfully** making a deal); 練成武功 (**successfully** trained in martial art)

> *很难办成的事情*

很难办**成** = hard to **successfully** do

> 穿成这样

穿**成**这样 = dress (**to become**) like this

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and thorough answer!

Answer (score 1):

In the last 2 examples you are right , but in the first one 成 means 成为(become) which can not be replaced by 完 or 好.